# What is the earliest stardate mentioned by a character?

Tags: star-trek, stardate

In all the series and movies, what is the earliest stardate mentioned by a character?

This question is specifically about a stardate spoken by someone visible on screen, just off screen or a voice over and not one seen (written on paper, visible on a screen, etc.) or spoken by a computer.

Comment: Why the restriction?

Comment: @ThePopMachine No reason in particular. I just wanted to narrow it down a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chronologically, the earliest is 2233.04, the stardate of Nero's arrival in *Star Trek (2009)*:

> **Ayel:** What is the current stardate?
>
> **Captain Robau:** Stardate? It's twenty-two thirty-three zero four.
>
> <sup><sub>*Star Trek (2009)*</sub></sup>

An earlier one is *referenced* in the *Enterprise* episode "Damage", but the stardate itself is not spoken aloud:

> **T'Pol:** I discovered a set of coordinates embedded in the document.
>
> **Archer:** It's not a star system.
>
> **T'Pol:** There was another embedded number. A stardate, three days from now.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Star Trek: Enterprise* Season 3 Episode 19: "Damage"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/71.htm)</sub></sup>

Finally, although the date it references is actually later than the one from *Star Trek (2009)*, the smallest number given as a stardate is in the first episode of *Discovery*:

> **Burnham:** First Officer's Log, Stardate 1207.3. On Earth, it's May 11, 2256. A Sunday.
>
> <sup>*Star Trek: Discovery* Season 1 Episode 1: "The Vulcan Hello"</sup>

Despite being a smaller number, the episode takes place about 30 years after *Star Trek (2009)*; this is likely in reference to the stardates in the original series, which were invented willy-nilly by the episode writers.